# Getting error trying to GROUP BY an XML column in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I've been googling for solutions trying to correct a SQL error when trying to GROUP BY an XML column and I've tried different solutions such as CONVERT and CAST of the column as suggested in various posts but to no avail.  Any suggestions on how to make this work?  Any help/direction would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyyMMddhhmmssf', 'en-US') as  [Message Transmission Date/Time] 
    ,tpi2.PolicySysID
    ,LEFT(ISNULL(tpi2.AgentCd,'') + SPACE(10),10) as [AgentCd]
    ,'AUTO ' as [Line of Business Routing Code]             
    ,CASE 
        WHEN CAST(tpi2.DocumentData.value('(/IW/form/@name)[1]','varchar(max)') as varchar(max)) = 'WELCOME LETTER' THEN 'NBS'
        WHEN CAST(tpi2.DocumentData.value('(/IW/form/@name)[1]','varchar(max)') as varchar(max)) = 'ENDORSEMENT' THEN 'PCH'
        WHEN CAST(tpi2.DocumentData.value('(/IW/form/@name)[1]','varchar(max)') as varchar(max)) = 'REINSTATEMENT NOTICE' THEN 'REI'
        WHEN CAST(tpi2.DocumentData.value('(/IW/form/@name)[1]','varchar(max)') as varchar(max)) = 'RENEWAL OFFER' THEN 'RWQ'
        WHEN CAST(tpi2.DocumentData.value('(/IW/form/@name)[1]','varchar(max)') as varchar(max)) = 'NON-RENEWAL NOTICE' THEN 'RWX'
        WHEN CAST(tpi2.DocumentData.value('(/IW/form/@name)[1]','varchar(max)') as varchar(max)) = 'CANCELLATION NOTICE' THEN 'XLC'
    END as [Cycle/Business Purpose]
    ,tpi2.[Transaction Date] as [Transaction Date]                                                                      
    ,tpi2.[Transaction Effective Date] as [Transaction Effective Date]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN tpcbpv2.RN = 1 THEN MAX(LEFT(ISNULL(tpcbpv2.PolicyVehicleSysID,'') + SPACE(4),4)) 
    END as [Company Vehicle Number 1]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN tpcbpv2.RN = 1 THEN MAX(LEFT(ISNULL(tpcbpv2.vYear,'') + SPACE(4),4)) 
    END as [Vehicle Year 1]
    ,CASE   
        WHEN tpcbpv2.RN = 1 THEN MAX(LEFT(ISNULL(tpcbpv2.vMake,'') + SPACE(20),20))
    END as [Vehicle Make 1]
    ,CASE
        WHEN tpcbpv2.RN = 1 THEN MAX(LEFT(ISNULL(tpcbpv2.vModel,'') + SPACE(20),20))
    END as [Vehicle Model 1]
    ,CASE
        WHEN tpcbpv2.RN = 1 THEN MAX(LEFT(ISNULL(tpcbpv2.vBody,'') + SPACE(5),5))
    END as [Vehicle Body Type 1]
    ,CASE
        WHEN tpcbpv2.RN = 1 THEN MAX(LEFT(ISNULL(tpcbpv2.VIN,'') + SPACE(25),25))
    END as [VIN 1]
FROM #tempPolicyInfo tpi2
GROUP BY tpi2.PolicySysID, tpi2.AgentCd, CAST(tpi2.DocumentData as xml), tpi2.[Transaction Date], tpi2.[Transaction Effective Date]
```

Here is the error:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 182
Column '#tempPolicyInfo.DocumentData' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 182
Column '#tempPolicyInfo.DocumentData' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 182
Column '#tempPolicyInfo.DocumentData' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 182
Column '#tempPolicyInfo.DocumentData' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 182
Column '#tempPolicyInfo.DocumentData' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 182
Column '#tempPolicyInfo.DocumentData' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Comment: The error appear to be telling you the problem, `tpi2.DocumentData` *isn't* in your `GROUP BY` clause;`CAST(tpi2.DocumentData as xml)` is. Considering that to use the `value` operator `tpi2.DocumentData` has to already be the `xml` datatype, I'm not sure why you are casting it in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Larnu, I had corrected the SQL statement and put in the MAX columns that then required a GROUP BY.

Comment: I also highly recommend you get rid of `FORMAT`, it poorly awfully. Leave the formatting to the presentation layer, and if you *must* then use `CONVERT` and style codes; it's perform 10's of times faster

Comment: There is NO PRESENTATION layer as this just for a fixed-width file.

Comment: Then switch to `CONVERT` and style codes; like I mentioned.

Comment: This is an overly simplfied example, but even this shows how much faster (about twice as fast) `CONVERT` is over `FORMAT`: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dcf986020ac48f1c29ffef0d5d7e7b2b)

Comment: Also, I *assume* you actually want `yyyyMMddHHmmssf`; otherwise you have no way of telling the difference between `00:00:00` and `12:00:00`; as they will both appear as `12:00:00` (which would be a significant lose of data). Either way, the answer is in my initial comment; this appears to be a typographical error.

Comment: Thanks Larnu for your comments on the FORMAT but the original question is the GROUP BY an XML column (5th column in the SQL statement).  Any thoughts on that?  Thanks.

Comment: I gave my thoughts in the first comment, @Melinda . To repeat myself: *"The error appears to be telling you the problem, `tpi2.DocumentData` **isn't** in your `GROUP BY` clause; `CAST(tpi2.DocumentData as xml)` is.*" (Hint: `tpi2.DocumentData` and `CAST(tpi2.DocumentData as xml)` **aren't** the same expression.) "*Considering that to use the `value` operator `tpi2.DocumentData` has to already be the `xml` datatype, so I'm not sure why you are casting it* (to an `xml`) *in the `GROUP BY`."*

Comment: @Larnu, my apologies.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Larnu, in such cases I prefer to use `APPLY` to add a no-XML column and use this to proceed. You might be interested in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Without a running sample it is hard to help you, but you might try something along this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyyMMddhhmmssf', 'en-US') as  [Message Transmission Date/Time] 
    ,tpi2.PolicySysID
    ,LEFT(ISNULL(tpi2.AgentCd,'') + SPACE(10),10) as [AgentCd]
    ,'AUTO ' as [Line of Business Routing Code]             
    ,CASE DocData.FormName
        WHEN 'WELCOME LETTER' THEN 'NBS'
        WHEN 'ENDORSEMENT' THEN 'PCH'
        WHEN 'REINSTATEMENT NOTICE' THEN 'REI'
        WHEN 'RENEWAL OFFER' THEN 'RWQ'
        WHEN 'NON-RENEWAL NOTICE' THEN 'RWX'
        WHEN 'CANCELLATION NOTICE' THEN 'XLC'
    END as [Cycle/Business Purpose]
    ,tpi2.[Transaction Date] as [Transaction Date]                                                                      
    ,tpi2.[Transaction Effective Date] as [Transaction Effective Date]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN tpcbpv2.RN = 1 THEN MAX(LEFT(ISNULL(tpcbpv2.PolicyVehicleSysID,'') + SPACE(4),4)) 
    END as [Company Vehicle Number 1]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN tpcbpv2.RN = 1 THEN MAX(LEFT(ISNULL(tpcbpv2.vYear,'') + SPACE(4),4)) 
    END as [Vehicle Year 1]
    ,CASE   
        WHEN tpcbpv2.RN = 1 THEN MAX(LEFT(ISNULL(tpcbpv2.vMake,'') + SPACE(20),20))
    END as [Vehicle Make 1]
    ,CASE
        WHEN tpcbpv2.RN = 1 THEN MAX(LEFT(ISNULL(tpcbpv2.vModel,'') + SPACE(20),20))
    END as [Vehicle Model 1]
    ,CASE
        WHEN tpcbpv2.RN = 1 THEN MAX(LEFT(ISNULL(tpcbpv2.vBody,'') + SPACE(5),5))
    END as [Vehicle Body Type 1]
    ,CASE
        WHEN tpcbpv2.RN = 1 THEN MAX(LEFT(ISNULL(tpcbpv2.VIN,'') + SPACE(25),25))
    END as [VIN 1]
FROM #tempPolicyInfo tpi2
OUTER APPLY(SELECT tpi2.DocumentData.value('(/IW/form/@name)[1]','varchar(max)')) DocData(FormName)
GROUP BY tpi2.PolicySysID, tpi2.AgentCd, DocData.FormName, tpi2.[Transaction Date], tpi2.[Transaction Effective Date];
```

The idea is, to us `APPLY` to compute an additional column *row-wise* and add this string-expression to the grouping list. As a side effect, your `CASE` is easier to maintain...